# passing multidimensional arrays to function

Tags: c++

I have a method in my class which uses a 3dimensional tfpairexp as input parameter. and I need to use the values in tfpairexp later.

```
void calctfpairexp (int tf1, int tf2, double tfpairexp[][2][3]) 
{

    int ctr,c;
    for (int j = 0; j < cchips && (c = chips[j].crepls); j += c)
    {
        int ctrl_no=0;
        for (int *p = chips[j].ctrl ; p && (ctr=*p)>=0; ++p,ctrl_no++)  {

            for (int k = 0; k < c; ++k)
            {

                tfpairexp[j][ctrl_no][k]=interactionFunc(2,3,1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I call the method inside the class like this:
`calctfpairexp(tf1,tf2,tfpairexp);`
and I need to use values inside tfpairexp in next lines.
but the compiler gives error in this line:

```
`calctfpairexp(tf1,tf2,tfpairexp);`
```

It says that it can't find the suitable the suitable funciton for calctfpairexp. any idea?

Comment: Have you considered using a class such as `boost::multi_array`?

Comment: hi. how should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect a syntax error from that function declaration, as the array param declaration is invalid.  You need:

```
void calctfpairexp (int tf1, int tf2, double tfpairexp[][2][3])
```

the array index stuff comes AFTER the param declarator

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this mistake. yeah it solved the problem with the funciton. but still I get an error when calling the function. it says that it can't find the suitable funciton. tfpairexp=new double [cchips][max_ctrl_no][max_rep_no];

Comment: You need `double (*tfpairexp)[2][3] = new double[chips][2][3]` -- the trailing dimensions must be constants and must match what the function expects.  Otherwise you'll get the 'no suitable function' error.

Answer (score 0):

And when using this prototype?

```
void calctfpairexp (int tf1, int tf2, double *** tfpairexp)
```

Allocation of a 3 dimensional array:

```
int w = 4;
int h = 5;
int d = 10;
double *** ary = new double ** [w];
for(int i=0; i<w; ++i){
    ary[i] = new double * [h];
    for(int j=0; j<h; ++j){
        ary[i][j] = new double [d];
    }
}
```

Deallocation:

```
for(int i=0; i<w; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<h; ++j){
        delete [] ary[i][j];
    }
    delete [] ary[i];
}
delete [] ary;
```

Comment: thanks. this way there is no error in the calctfpairexp. but here: double tfpairexp[cchips][max_ctrl_no][max_rep_no];
         calctfpairexp(tf1,tf2,tfpairexp); it says that no suitable function for calctfpairexp can be found.

Comment: You might dynamically allocate that array using `new` or `malloc`.

Comment: You've completely changed the meaning -- changing the multidim array into an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to single dim arrays, which is not at all the same thing, even though you can use the same syntax to access it.

Comment: both this way: double tfpairexp[cchips][max_ctrl_no][max_rep_no]; and this way: double ***tfpairexp it works. Now the error is when I call the funciton: calctfpairexp(tf1,tf2,tfpairexp);

Comment: why can't I use the array instead of pointers in the function parameters, as I have written in the first place?

Comment: You can't pass a `double ary[1][2][3]` to `void func(double ***)` but you can pass it to `void func(double [][2][3])` as long as the two last dimensions are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reference to typecheck the sizes :

```
void calctfpairexp (int tf1, int tf2, double (&tfpairexp)[][2][3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on GCC and it does not give compiler error.  Since I don't have any other part of source code, I take them out

```
double interactionFunc(int i, int j, int k) { return 0; }
void calctfpairexp (int tf1, int tf2, double tfpairexp[][2][3])
{

    int ctr, c;
    for (int j = 0; j < ctr; j += c)
    {
        int ctrl_no=0;
        for (int k = 0; k < c; ++k, ctrl_no++)
        {

            tfpairexp[j][ctrl_no][k]=interactionFunc(2,3,1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    double d[1][2][3];
    calctfpairexp(1, 2, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation results:

```
super@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ g++ q1.cpp
super@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5
```

Nothing wrong.  I don't think it's the declaration that causes problem.  You might want to look elsewhere.